# Docker RUN command in exec form not working

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm building a docker image based on Alpine.

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add lighttpd \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

ENV COLOR red

COPY ./index.html /var/www/localhost/htdocs

RUN /bin/ash -c 'echo abcd'
#working
RUN /bin/ash -c "echo $COLOR; sed -i -e 's/red/\$COLOR/g' /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html; cat /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html;"
#not working
# RUN ["sh", "-c", "echo $COLOR; sed -i -e 's/red/\$COLOR/g' /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html; cat /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html;"]

CMD ["lighttpd","-D","-f","/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"]
```

When I run in shell form it's working fine, but when I run in exec form it's giving

> /bin/sh: [sh,: not found

I tried using `bin/sh`, `sh`, `bin/ash`, `ash`. Same error for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell is responsible for expanding variables, but only variable in double quotes will be expanded.

Your error comes from wrong `\` before `$COLOR`, in fact it did no meaning for you to get the value from shell, the correct way is next:

```
RUN ["sh", "-c", "echo $COLOR; sed -i -e \"s/red/$COLOR/g\" /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html; cat /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.html;"]
```

A minimal example to show the effect, FYI:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine
ENV COLOR rednew
RUN echo "red" > /tmp/index.html
RUN ["sh", "-c", "sed -i -e \"s/red/$COLOR/g\" /tmp/index.html; cat /tmp/index.html;"]
```

**Result:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 . --no-cache                                                                                              
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine
 ---> 28f6e2705743
Step 2/4 : ENV COLOR rednew
 ---> Running in 05c43146fab0
Removing intermediate container 05c43146fab0
 ---> 28ea1434e626
Step 3/4 : RUN echo "red" > /tmp/index.html
 ---> Running in 2c8fbbc5fd10
Removing intermediate container 2c8fbbc5fd10
 ---> f884892ad8c4
Step 4/4 : RUN ["sh", "-c", "sed -i -e \"s/red/$COLOR/g\" /tmp/index.html; cat /tmp/index.html;"]
 ---> Running in 6930b3d03438
rednew
Removing intermediate container 6930b3d03438
 ---> b770475672cc
Successfully built b770475672cc
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

Comment: The error is kinda misleading one.. I was just focusing on first argument, when it said `/bin/sh: [sh,: not found`.